# How to get city name by ip in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, ip, tracking

Please help me to find cityname according to ip. Let me explain.

I am developing a webpage where I want it to automatically fetch the city name where it is opened and it should also display the location in the google map automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an IP to location API, like these:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

http://www.ipaddressapi.com/ ($)

Or manage to get data from other sources like:

http://www.iplocation.net/

http://ip2loc.jerodsanto.net/

Comment: Another one worth mentioning: http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location (free version exists, but only paid version has city precision if I remember correctly)

Comment: It's also worth saying that this method can be horribly inaccurate. The closest you can say for me is "United Kingdom", certainly not down to regional level, let alone town.

Answer (score 1):

Another source is: https://www.geoip-db.com They provide a JSON and JSONP-callback solution.

- JSON: https://geoip-db.com/json/
- JSONP: https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback

A jQuery example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Geo City Locator</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body > 
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></spa></div>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span></div>    

    <script>
      $.getJSON('https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=?').done(function(location) {
        $('#country').html(location.country_name);
        $('#state').html(location.state);
        $('#city').html(location.city);
        $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
        $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
        $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);               
     });
</script>
```